# Docker-compose - module import issue

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I am working on a Flask app and my `docker-compose.yml` is not able to find my config folder. I have `__init__.py` files at every levels and I tried to add/remove the config path from my `docker-compose.yml` file but still the same issue. This is my project structure:

```
.
├── ...
├── web_messaging                    
│   ├── app.py 
│   ├── __init__.py        
│   ├── ...       
│   └── config 
│       ├── settings.py 
│       ├── gunicorn.py
│       └── __init__.py
│            
├── __init__py             
├── .env             
├── requirements.txt              
├── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile
```

When I am running `docker-compose up --build`, I am getting this error:

```
website_1  | - 'config' not found.
website_1  | 
website_1  | Original exception:
website_1  | 
website_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
website_1  | [2021-04-04 15:23:26 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
website_1  | [2021-04-04 15:23:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
website_1  | [2021-04-04 15:23:26 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  website:
    build: .
    command: >
      gunicorn -c "python:web_messaging.config.gunicorn" --reload "web_messaging.app:create_app()"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    volumes:
      - '.:/web_messaging'
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
```

**app.py**

```
def create_app(settings_override=None):
    """
    Create a Flask application using the app factory pattern.

    :param settings_override: Override settings
    :return: Flask app
    """
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_object('config.settings')
    app.config.from_pyfile('settings.py', silent=True)

    if settings_override:
        app.config.update(settings_override)

    error_templates(app)
    app.register_blueprint(user)
    app.register_blueprint(texting)
    extensions(app)
    configure_context_processors(app)
    return app
...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.5-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y \
  build-essential libpq-dev --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /web_messaging
RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD gunicorn -c "python:web_messaging.config.gunicorn" "web_messaging.app:create_app()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I solved it. The `config` folder must be outside of the `main_messaging` folder,